# backbone.js collection not responding to .each

Tags: collections, backbone.js

I have what should be very simple. I create a new collection, and I want to pass it to a render and add the collection models to the page.

```
get_results: function(){
    $.getJson(this.url,function(response){
        this.search_results = new Kitchon.Collections.searchList(response);
        console.log(this.search_results);
        this.search_results.each(this.render_match);
    }
},
render_match: function(model){
    console.log(model)
},
```

This returns an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

my collection has an ordinary structure

```
_byCid: Object
_byId: Object
_onModelEvent: function () { [native code] }
_removeReference: function () { [native code] }
length: 7
models: Array[7]
__proto__: o
```

I've tried LOTS of things, but one thing that stuck out was maybe I had to pass 
`this.search_results.models.each(this.render_match);` as that is the actual array, but if I do that I get a `Uncaught typeError: Object [object Object],[object Object],...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you lose the execution context when callback function for each method is called

use `_.bind(this.render_match, this)` when passing callback to make sure that `render_match` has the right context

and you were getting error because you didn't wrap the callback function for `getJson` method neither. You have to use underscore `bind` method there as well.

You should read a bit about javascript `this` and how to tame it - try here http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/

Correct code should look more or less like this...

```
get_results: function(){

    $.getJSON(this.url, _.bind(function(response){

        this.search_results = new Kitchon.Collections.searchList(response);
        console.log(this.search_results);
        this.search_results.each(_.bind(this.render_match, this));
    }, this));
},
render_match: function(model){

    console.log(model)
},
```

Though from what I seee - I assume the code you've shown here is either a model or collection - is handling rendering the view - you shouldn't do that! Models and Collections are only to store and parse data - all rendering and controlling application flow should be done in the View(Controllers) with help of the Router.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I knew it was somehow getting lost with 'this', but I wasn't sure how to get that working. The article from Yehuda is a great addition. It's tough to search 'this' and get back relevant results.

Answer (score 3):

`$.getJson` changes the `this` reference. Many methods in jquery do that, so the value of `this.render_match` is null. You pass null to `each` and it fails.

To solve that, create a reference to this (like `var _this = this;`) before `$.getJson` and use it instead of `this`. Code should be like below:

```
get_results: function(){
    var _this = this;
    $.getJson(this.url,function(response){
        _this.search_results = new Kitchon.Collections.searchList(response);
        console.log(_this.search_results);
        _this.search_results.each(_this.render_match);
    }
},
render_match: function(model){
    console.log(model)
},
```

Comment: you lost the `this` context again in the each loop - check my answer

Answer (score -1):

Just taking a stab here (I don't know anything about Backbone.js), but isn't this what you are looking for:

```
$.each(this.search_results, function(index, value) { 
  alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Backbone.js is mapping a lot of the underscore.js methods to the Collections - you don't need to and shouldn't be using jquery each when you have underscorejs at hand - it's implementation is tad faster + this.search_results isn't a real Array but rather Backbone.Collection instance - if you wanted to iterate over the models directly you'd need to access the `models` attribute on the collection.